# app.use(morgan("dev")) Not working, my middleware works when I write it in app.js and it does not work when I write it in server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, middleware, morgan

Here is my ***App.js*** file

```
const express = require("express");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const movieRouter = require("./routes/movieRoutes");
const userRouter = require("./routes/userRoutes");

const app = express();
dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });


app.use(express.json());
//Mounting routes
app.use("/kramank-api/v1/movies", movieRouter);
app.use("/kramank-api/v1/users", userRouter);
app.use(express.static("./"));
module.exports = app;
```

Here is my ***Server.js*** file

```
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const morgan = require("morgan");
const app = require("./app");

dotenv.config({ path: "./config.env" });

const DB = process.env.DATABASE.replace(
  "<password>",
  process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD
);

mongoose
  .connect(DB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connection to Database succesful ");
  });

const portNumber = 8080;
app.use(morgan("dev"));
app.listen(portNumber, "127.0.0.1", () => {
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
  console.log(`Server is now running on port  ${portNumber} ⚡`);
});
```

**The problem**
When I write `app.use(morgan("dev"))` in the **app.js** file it works, but when I write it in the **server.js** file (the way I have pasted my code above) **it does not work** and doesn't even give any errors.

Comment: `When I write app.use(morgan("dev")) in the app.js file it works,` At what line are you writing this code in your app.js?

Comment: right above app.use(express.json()) in app.js, but it works when I write it in app.js  but using it in server.js does nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you put it in your `server.js` file, it's the very last route/middleware declaration.  That means it never gets called except when no other route has taken the request.

Middleware that you want to get called for all routes must be defined BEFORE any of the route definitions that you want it to run before.  The order of registering these matters.

In my opinion, middleware like this belongs in your `app.js` file so you can register this middleware first, right after you create the `app` object and before any other routes.